# MySQL : #1054 - Unknown column 'messages.app_id' in 'on clause'

Tags: mysql, sql

I got this `MySQL` query, I need to join both tables `apps` and `contacts`, but I am getting this error:

```
MySQL said: Documentation

#1054 - Unknown column 'messages.app_id' in 'on clause'
```

My query:

```
SELECT
  `messages`.*,
  (
    SELECT
      COUNT(*)
    FROM
      messages AS message
    WHERE
      message.app_id = `messages`.`app_id`
      AND message.contact_id = `messages`.`contact_id`
      AND message.status = "sent"
  ) AS `unread_count`
FROM
  `messages`,
  (
    SELECT
      `contact_id`,
      max(`created_at`) as latest_created_at
    FROM
      `messages`
    GROUP BY
      `contact_id`, `app_id`
  ) AS `max_created_at`
INNER JOIN `apps` AS `apps` ON `messages.app_id` = `apps`.`id` 
INNER JOIN `contacts` AS `contacts` ON `messages.contact_id` = `contacts`.`id` 
WHERE
  `messages`.`app_id` = 1
  AND `messages`.`contact_id` = max_created_at.`contact_id`
  AND `messages`.`created_at` = max_created_at.latest_created_at
```

what exactly is wrong here?

Comment: practically everywhere but here `messages.app_id` and `messages.contact_id` you have correctly backticked table and column names separately. Voting to close as typo..

Comment: Don't mix implicit and explicit joins, it's simply too confusing. Switch to the modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (**without errors**), easier to read (and maintain), and easier to convert to outer join if needed. (Explicit JOINS are evaluated _before_ implicit ones.)

Answer (score 0):

Don't use old school comma separated table lists, especially not mixed with more *"modern"* join syntax. You also skipped `app_id` in your select list and join for `max_created_at`. The correlated subquery for `unread_count` is unnecessary as you can add it to `max_created_at` subquery:

```
SELECT
  `messages`.*,
  `max_created_at`.`unread_count`
FROM `messages`
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT
        `contact_id`,
        `app_id`,
        MAX(`created_at`) AS `latest_created_at`,
        COUNT(IF(`status` = 'sent', 1, NULL)) AS `unread_count`
    FROM `messages`
    GROUP BY `contact_id`, `app_id`
) AS `max_created_at`
    ON `messages`.`contact_id` = `max_created_at`.`contact_id`
    AND `messages`.`app_id` = `max_created_at`.`app_id`
    AND `messages`.`created_at` = `max_created_at`.`latest_created_at`
INNER JOIN `apps`
    ON `messages`.`app_id` = `apps`.`id` 
INNER JOIN `contacts`
    ON `messages`.`contact_id` = `contacts`.`id` 
WHERE `messages`.`app_id` = 1;
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you are simply missing a backtick with the table name -

```
SELECT
  `messages`.*,
  (
    SELECT
      COUNT(*)
    FROM
      messages AS message
    WHERE
      message.app_id = `messages`.`app_id`
      AND message.contact_id = `messages`.`contact_id`
      AND message.status = "sent"
  ) AS `unread_count`
FROM
  `messages`,
  (
    SELECT
      `contact_id`,
      max(`created_at`) as latest_created_at
    FROM
      `messages`
    GROUP BY
      `contact_id`, `app_id`
  ) AS `max_created_at`
INNER JOIN `apps` AS `apps` ON `messages`.`app_id` = `apps`.`id`                    -- I have added here
INNER JOIN `contacts` AS `contacts` ON `messages`.`contact_id` = `contacts`.`id`     -- I have added here
WHERE
  `messages`.`app_id` = 1
  AND `messages`.`contact_id` = max_created_at.`contact_id`
  AND `messages`.`created_at` = max_created_at.latest_created_at
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply, but sadly its still giving the error `#1054 - Unknown column 'messages.app_id' in 'on clause'` even after adding the backtick

Comment: Still out of scope. See my comment above.